# Minimax not scoring branches correctly in tic-tac-toe

Tags: c, algorithm, tic-tac-toe, minimax

I'm trying to create a perfect tic-tac-toe game in C. I'm using a 2D array to keep track of the board.

I have narrowed the issue down to the way my `minimax` function is scoring each potential move, but I am having trouble debugging it because the error happens around the second move usually, and I cannot keep track of all the potential game states from that point.

The computer goes first, and is always 'X'. `minimax` is being called from within a `computerMove` function which tries each available move and then minimaxes them. It takes the value returned for the potential game state from `minimax` as a temporary score and compares it to the current top score. I am confident that part of the program is working. The problem lies in the `minimax` function itself

Here is the important parts of my code:

```
int minimax(char board[][3], char maxPlayer) // +10 -> X wins 
{                                            // -10 -> O wins
    char minPlayer;                          //   0 -> draw
    int scores[3][3];
    if (maxPlayer == 'X') minPlayer = 'O';
    else minPlayer = 'X';
    int topScore = 0;

    // initializing scores to ensure a move is selected
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            scores[i][j] = -11;
        }
    }

    // check for terminal state
    if (isWinning(board,'X') || isWinning(board,'O') || 
    !moveAvailable(board)) {
        if (isWinning(board,'X')) return 10;
        else if (isWinning(board,'O')) return -10;
        else return 0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            if (board[i][j] == 'U') { 
                board[i][j] = maxPlayer;                // try the move
                scores[i][j] = minimax(board,minPlayer);// minimax it
                board[i][j] = 'U';                      // undo the move
            }
        }
    }  

    // if calling minimax for computer, maximize the score
    if (maxPlayer == 'X') {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                if (scores[i][j] > topScore && scores[i][j] != -11) 
                    topScore = scores[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    // if calling minimax for human, minimize the score
    else if (maxPlayer == 'O') {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                if (scores[i][j] < topScore && scores[i][j] != -11) 
                    topScore = scores[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return topScore;
}
```

Comment: My best bet is this line: `if (board[i][j] == 'U') {`. This condition is never true I guess

Comment: this line: `scores[row][column] = -11; // set all to 'O' wins` is not correct.  Per the other commentary on the signature statement of the function, 'O' wins is -10, not -11

Comment: Each recursion is starting with a new, uninitialized version of `scores[][]`  This is probably not correct.

Comment: The `scores` values are never other than 0, -11, and +10.  I think the scores should be accumulative. I.E. initialize each new `scores` to all 0, then each recursive call to `minimax()` should result in the upper level `scores` being incremented (perhaps by -10) from the result of the recursive calls to `minimax()`

Comment: @VidorVistrom the board initially contains all Us I guess, so he does want this check.

Comment: @user3629249 he uses `scores[row][column] = -11;` as a "slotAlreadyUsed" boolean, not really as a score, so he basically wants a value that is never used for a true score. He does want a new score[][] at each step, since the score of each move depends on the state of the board. The scores should not be incremental across the depth, you only want the max or the min of them depending on the layer you're at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with `topScore` initialization:

- You should initialise `topScore` at 11 or -11 depending on who plays, not 0, otherwise both players will believe they can always reach at least a draw (which is not the case), starting at depth 2.
- in terms of good practices (imho), I think that the last two loops should be grouped into one, with the `if (maxPlayer == 'X')` condition inside of it, just before updating `topScore`. Also, you should skip all positions where `board[i][j]!='U'`, it's easier to understand than lookinf for `-11` in scores (which is good though).